# Angular 15: error An unexpected error occurred: "could not find a copy of webpack-dev-server to link in c:path\\node_module

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, package.json, webpack-dev-server

Angular 15: error An unexpected error occurred: "could not find a copy of webpack-dev-server to link in c:path\node_module. I'm trying to install the package dependencies using yarn and it errors with above error.
The project install and build fine with the sometime ago, however, recently it is asking for webpack-dev-server and I don't have it explicitly configured in other Angular projects, wondering what dose it do and why is it asking me now. Thanking in advance for help and comments.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "@website",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:staged": "lint-staged",
    "lint:styles": "./node_modules/.bin/stylelint src/**/*.scss --fix",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "cypress:run": "cypress run",
    "cypress:component": "cypress open --component",
    "format": "yarn prettier --write .",
    "prepare": "cd ../.. && husky install src/website-remote-iam/.husky"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js, ts}": [
      "eslint --quiet --fix"
    ],
    "*.{json, md, html, js, ts}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ],
    "*.scss": [
      "stylelint src/**/*.scss"
    ]
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "15.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "15.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "15.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "15.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "15.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "15.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "15.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "15.0.2",
    "@ngxs/store": "3.7.6",
    "rxjs": "7.6.0",
    "tslib": "2.4.1",
    "zone.js": "0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "15.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "15.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "15.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "15.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "15.0.2",
    "@cypress/schematic": "2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "4.3.1",
    "@types/node": "18.11.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.45.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.45.1",
    "cypress": "11.2.0",
    "eslint": "8.18.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.12.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.2.1",
    "husky": "8.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "4.5.0",
    "karma": "6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "13.0.3",
    "ngx-build-plus": "15.0.0",
    "prettier": "2.8.0",
    "prettier-eslint": "15.0.1",
    "pretty-quick": "3.1.3",
    "serverless-localstack": "1.0.0",
    "stylelint": "14.15.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier-scss": "0.0.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss": "6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  }
}
```

Installed
npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server
also needed install
npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-middleware webpack-hot-middleware
it bypass this error but did not build stating the cli version mismatch

Comment: Try `ng serve --verbose` and post the error